# Is there any way to execute ex command without adding it to the command history?

Tags: startup, command-history

When I start `vim`, I always use `-s SCRIPT_FILE_NAME` option to execute additional commands. In `SCRIPT_FILE_NAME`, some ex commands are written. Let `COMM` denote the additional commands in the file. The problem is that `COMM` is added to command history. For example, when I

1. start `vim` and execute `:echo` and exit with `:q`
2. and start `vim` again

the expected contents of the command history (which can be seen via `q:`) are

```
: 48 echo
: 49 q
```

but the actual contents are

```
: 48 echo
: 49 q
: 50 COMM1
: 51 COMM2
      ︙
: 60 COMM11
```

and this is truly annoying. (Assume `COMM` consists of a hundread of commands.)

Is there any way to avoid this?

---

NOTE1: Because the execution order is different between commands in `.vimrc` and those in `SCRIPT_FILE_NAME`, I cannot move `COMM` to `.vimrc`. In other words, there **is** a reason why I use `-s` option in addition to `.vimrc`.

NOTE2: Of course, it is possible to execute `sed` command between the first and second step above to remove the undesired lines. However, doing like this isn't elegant, I think. I wonder if there is a better solution supplied by `vim` by default.

---

Update:

By putting all of `COMM` into a function in `.vimrc` and calling it from `SCRIPT_FILE_NAME`, the number of items added to the history can be decreased to one. But I'd still like to decrease it to zero if I can.

Comment: Not sure if we can tell vim to *skip* the recording of a command. But [`:h histdel()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#histdel()) may help. Try to put `call histdel(':', -1)` at the end of your function.

Comment: @perelo Worked perfectly. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I always use `-s SCRIPT_FILE_NAME` option to execute additional commands. In `SCRIPT_FILE_NAME`, some ex commands are written.

So [`-s {scriptin}`](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#-s) or the equivalent [`:source!`](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#%3Asource%21) command are meant to read the contents of a file and execute those as *Normal* mode commands.

They fully reuse normal mode key processing. As such, Ex commands entered with `:` will be added to history. There doesn't seem to be much you can really do about that.

If you're primarily using this mechanism to run Ex commands, then turn this around. Turn it into an Ex script instead (which means you can drop the `:`s), then you can use the [`:source`](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#%3Asource%21) command to load it.

If you have parts of the script that are using Normal mode commands, you can use the [`:normal!`](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#%3Anormal) command to enter them, turning that into an Ex command that you can use as part of the script.

You mentioned *"putting all of `COMM` into a function in `.vimrc` and calling it from `SCRIPT_FILE_NAME`"*, so it sounds like you were able to accomplish that already, since `.vimrc` and `function` are both comprised of Ex mode commands.

Once you have your Ex script, you can then use the [`-c`](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#-c) command-line option to source it:

```
$ vim -c 'source SCRIPT_FILE_NAME.vim' ...
```

Or, if you have it as a function in your `.vimrc`:

```
$ vim -c 'call MyInitFunc()' ...
```

That should work as expected, without polluting the Vim command history.

---

Also, about this:

> Because the execution order is different between commands in `.vimrc` and those in `SCRIPT_FILE_NAME`, I cannot move `COMM` to `.vimrc`. In other words, there **is** a reason why I use `-s` option in addition to `.vimrc`.

Take a look at the [VimEnter](https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html#VimEnter) event of `autocmd`, it triggers once, around the same time as the `-c` script works. (I believe `-s` is a little later than both, but still close.)

If you want to *always* use the sequence of commands and you have only been using the external script because of the timing, then using VimEnter should solve this problem in a better way.

Use something like the following in your `.vimrc`:

```
function! MyInitFunc()
  COMM1
  COMM2
  COMM3
endfunction
augroup vimrc_initfunc
  autocmd!
  autocmd VimEnter * call MyInitFunc()
augroup END
```

(See also [`v:vim_did_enter`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#v%3Avim_did_enter), if you care about possibly re-running `MyInitFunc()` if you're reloading your `.vimrc` using `:source` during runtime.)

Comment: Thank you really much for your detailed answer. `-c 'source SCRIPT'` and `-c 'call FUNCTION'` worked as expected. And, I'm impressed by the sophisticated solution using `VimEnter`. That is enough in my case, so now I use `VimEnter` in my `.vimrc` and succeeded in making the bash alias for `vi` shorter.

Comment: Awesome @ynn, glad I could help! Ideally you shouldn't even need a bash alias for vim (it doesn't get triggered when vim is invoked by other tools such as git for commit messages), so feel free to ask further questions about what's in your alias, we can probably help you accomplish that from within Vim itself if at all possible!

Comment: I'm experiencing [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453595/prevent-vim-from-clearing-the-clipboard-on-exit) for a few years. In my environment, `VimLeave` doesn't help because the clipboard seems cleared **after** `VimLeave`. So I write out the clipboard contents to a file when `VimLeave` and by using `/usr/bin/vi; LOAD`, I avoid the problem where `LOAD` is the command to read the file into clipboard. This may be my-environment-specific and asking about that is duplicate. Since `:help` didn't tell me something later than `VimLeave`, I think the alias is needed maybe... :(

Comment: @ynn You should be able to make that work... Consider asking that here in Vi&Vim.SE, since you'll get more Vim experts here. I assume you're on Linux. Did you try the `xsel` solution? Do you see the contents of the clipboard if you try `"*p` or "+p`? Do both work, or only one of them?

Comment: Ah... I was really foolish. I forget the rule: more newly added `autocmd`s are executed later. Rearranging a series of commands in `.vimrc` solved the problem. Both `xsel` and `xclip` worked well. (Until today, probably I tried to call `LOAD` before I write out to the file...) Thanks to you, today I made my `.vimrc` more elegant and removed three bash functions. I can't thank you enough!

Comment: @ynn Really glad I got to help you today!